# Plot current position on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I am trying to plot the user's current position on a gmap. I think my code is close to being correct, however I am missing something:

**.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});

Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.7000, 23.3333),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {

    var initialLocation;
    var browserSupportFlag = new Boolean();

    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preffered)
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      browserSupportFlag = true;
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
      });
    }
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    else {
      browserSupportFlag = false;
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    }

  })
})
```

**.html**

```
<template name="map">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search">
      <input id="search" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The map is being displayed, and I see that the geolocator is turned on, but the current location is not centered and there is no marker. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know meteor but you don't seem to be adding any marker.

Comment: That would be the second step, I first need to plot the current location.